# Cannot type in login credentials in Red Hat

Tags: linux, rhel, gnome

Got stuck at the login window (Red Hat 6.5) as I cannot type in the login ID. No characters are accepted in the box. MouseOK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try another `tty` by pressing `ctrl+alt+F2` ?  Does the prompt show a `Username: ` prompt?

Comment: Yes, I did and it works. The machine has been power cycled and all came back to normal. Nevertheless, it will be good to understand what caused this behaviour.